# confused on how to create the Stripe ephemeral key in the APIClient.swift class

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

So for the last 2 days I've been stumped on how to implement this Stripe API, it's by far been the hardest thing to wrap my head around with. So I decided to integrate the Stripe functionality  using Firebase and Cloud Functions and I've been seeing that it's server-less which is great.

I've been trying to follow [this article on iOS Stripe API integration](https://www.iosapptemplates.com/blog/ios-development/stripe-firebase-swift) and [this article showing how to create the cloud functions involving Stripe](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/go-serverless-manage-payments-in-your-apps-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase-3528cfad770) and I so far have been able to create a Stripe customer upon new user creation. After that, I'm pretty much lost on how to do what I want to do next, which is create ephemeral keys.

I have this function I snagged from another SO post:

```
exports.createEphemeralKeys = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
var api_version = req.body.api_version;
var customerId = req.body.customerId;

if (!api_version) {
 res.status(400).end();
 return;
 }

 stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
  { customer: customerId },
  { stripe_version: api_version }, 

 function(err, key) {
   return res.send(key);
 });   
});
```

And this is the method in the `MyAPIClient.swift` file:

```
 func createCustomerKey(withAPIVersion apiVersion: String, completion: @escaping STPJSONResponseCompletionBlock) {
    let url = self.baseURL.appendingPathComponent("ephemeral_keys")
    var urlComponents = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)!
    urlComponents.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "api_version", value: apiVersion)]
    var request = URLRequest(url: urlComponents.url!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            response.statusCode == 200,
            let data = data,
            let json = ((try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any]) as [String : Any]??) else {
            completion(nil, error)
            return
        }
        completion(json, nil)
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

Now this is where I get confused, since integrating Stripe with Firebase is server-less, what are we supposed to input in the `baseURL`? Currently the `baseURL` variable is empty, but I'm also getting thrown errors that `.appendingPathComponent` is not available as well. Forgive me if this is a dumb question, but I'd much rather look like a complete idiot and eventually figure out how to successfully integrate this API, than not ask anything at all. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `baseURL` should be set to the URL where your Firebase functions live.  Have a look at [the Firebase documentation for invoking an HTTP function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#invoke_an_http_function) for details.

The URL will be something like this:

```
https://<region>-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/
```